# How to delete a file that is being used by another thread?

Tags: java, io, nio

I run a unit-test that checks my endpoints. When an endpoint are performs it will write logs to a log dir. I want to delete this log file after the unit test is finished. But I get the following Exception:

```
 java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\dev\IdeaProjects\users\src\main\resources\log\events The process cannot access the file, as this file is being used by another process.
```

I have the following method:

```
public static void deleteLogDir() throws IOException {
     String logEventPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") +  "/users/src/main/resources/log/events";
     Path path = Paths.get(logEventPath);
     Files.list(path).forEach(e -> {
            try {
                  Files.deleteIfExists(e);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                   e1.printStackTrace();
                }
     });
}


@AfterAll
public static void clear() throws IOException {
     deleteLogDir();
}
```

I don't open this file in any other program. When I am trying to delete this file in my main/java out of test/java directory It is deleted without any issue. When I even try to read from this file in test directory I get java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException.

How It possible to delete this log file?

Comment: Have you tried File.deleteOnExit()?

Comment: Yes, I try now, but it doesn't delete file too.

Comment: You might be able to use Java.io to get the file ACL info: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_io/1030__Java_nio_File_Owner_Permissions.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows OS files that are being used by other users are **locked** and can't be deleted.
The only solution will be to close the *Reader*, if you are using one, at the end of the test.

Or just move to Linux and forget about this kind of problems ;)

#### EDIT

Apparently shutdowning the LogManager worked for him. 
`LogManager.shutdown()`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Maybe you know how to close Log4j2 Loggers reader that lock this file. I try to add  LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
at the start of my method but it still doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe you could try `LogManager.shutdown()` (only in *Log4j2*). It's a synchrounous call so it will block untill it finishes, you will maybe have to implement a `synchronized` method.  Let me know if this works, it's interessting

Comment: Yes, LogManager.shutdown() is work, Thank you for yout help)